# Destructuring props not working in React JS storybooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am missing something here when I destructure my props. I am writing a story book but the issue seems like I am doing something wrong with destructuring.

This is my component

```
export function WrapTitle ({title,children}) : TitleProps & ChildrenProps){
 return (<>h1>{titles}</h1> {children}</>)
}
```

So in Stories When I pass like this it's not working

```
<Wraptitle {...args}><Wraptitle>
```

How I pass the args is (This is a storybook)

```
WithTitle.args = {
 title:'The is title'
}
```

and whenI pass like this its working

```
<Wraptitle title = {"This is header"}><Wraptitle>
```

Am I missing anything here

Comment: You forgot to add what `args` looks like. Also the code you have added has typos, hope that is not the mistake you are making in your own PC

Comment: @TusharShahi Can you add in answer, I didn't get it

Comment: <Wraptitle {...args}><Wraptitle> should be <Wraptitle> {...args}><Wraptitle>

Answer (score 0):

You have to write props.PROPERTY sintax, this will work:

```
export function WrapTitle (props) : TitleProps & ChildrenProps){
 return (<>h1>{props.title}</h1> {props.children}</>)
}
```